# MySQL trigger: use NEW as a table

Tags: mysql, trigger

In a trigger we may refer to inserted/updated values use NEW alias as a table. But it is NOT a table.

---

I insert some data into some table, and I need to update some another table during this insert. There is a lof of fields in both tables which matches to each other absolutely (names, datatypes, sizes and so on). So the simplest trigger text (for example, for insert) would be

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr
AFTER INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE table2 NATURAL JOIN NEW
    SET table2.field = SOMEFUNC(NEW.somefields);
```

However, NEW is not actually a table, and I expect to get an error message when the trigger is fired:

> Table 'DB_name.new' doesn't exist

**Question**: is there a way or trick to use NEW as a table for to use NATURAL JOIN strongly (not ON, WHERE or USING)?

Assume that the goal is: if the list of matched fields altered (synchronously in both tables) I do not need to edit the trigger.

Comment: Notice how it says `FOR EACH ROW`? The trigger scope is a single row, not a table or result set.

Comment: @mustaccio I know this and I understand this, including the reason. This is not a point of my question - I search does some "backdoor" exists on the SQL level (strongly, not more deep)...

Comment: Your best shot is probably to generate the trigger via script. The script can inspect the catalog, and construct the trigger

Comment: @Lennart Yes, creating the procedure which garbages the structures and constructs proper trigger script (or a template which feeds in manual inserting of SET clause) is an option.

Comment: this is after insert trigger, what if you would use natural join with table1 where table1.PKcol = NEW.PKcol?

Comment: @Nikita Error like "You cannot use the table which the trigger is defined on", of course...

Comment: just tested it on MySQL 8.0.12 and it works (but I used simple join, not natural)